# Python - Use an Unix socket which already exists

Tags: python, sockets, unix-socket

I run a Python program on an embedded system. This system runs a server that creates UNIX sockets.

```
def com(request):
    my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    my_socket.connect("/var/run/.json-cgi")
    my_socket.send(request)
    reply = my_socket.recv(4096)
    return repr(reply)
```

`/var/run/.json-cgi` is the socket created by the server. I send a http request that I wrote before and I passed in the arg of the function.
When I print the reply, I just get `''`.

I wonder if my program creates a new socket that has the same path than the server's one or if it uses the socket of the server.
I want to use the socket created by the server.

Did I forget something ?

Comment: 1) Is the server actively listening on the socket and accepting connections, and 2) if so, does changing `.send` to `.sendall` change the behaviour?

Comment: The server is always listening and accepts connections. This socket is also use by lighttpd (with FastCGI) and when I use `HTTPConnection` object on my own system and send data on the url defined by lighttpd, I get a response. Using `.sendall` does not change the behavior, I get the same reply : `''`.